How to retort when somebody says something you already know?

In my native language, when somebody says something you already know and it annoys you, you can say “Does it even need you to say it” or “Does it even need you to tell me that.” (These are literal translations.) They’re retorts. I’d like to know how to say that in English idiomatically. It’s not meant to be polite, so I don’t care if the expression’s rude.
Is “you needn’t tell me that” idiomatic in North America? I haven’t heard many people use “need” as a modal verb in North America. Thank you.


Yes, “you needn’t tell me that” is idiomatic, though recently it may have been overtaken by “you don’t need to tell me that”.

The questions are not exactly the same. In the post you mentioned, the PO wanted an expression that's "not really offensive", whereas I don't mind if the expression's offensive.

See this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107785/is-there-a-clean-version-of-no-sht-sherlock

In addition to the distinction offered by the OP (their not minding offensiveness), for what it's worth, unlike the previous questions cited, I don't see the requirement of obviousness anywhere in this question; merely that the OP was already aware of the "news."

My favourite British English phrase, not widely used these days is "Queen Anne's dead".  See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/where-does-the-idiom-queen-anne-is-dead-come-from

"Needless to say" is very used in all Englishes.

Doesn't it make a difference whether the statement is "commonsense" or it just happens that you already know (like some news or specialized wisdom)?

"Stale news".  But only to someone you know well enough to know they will not take offence.

"You're telling me," with emphasis on "me"

"Next you'll tell me that the sky is blue." Alternatively, you might cite the religion of the Pope or the defecatory practices of a wild bear.

If you really want to be offensive, you can tell them not to mansplain/femmesplain it to you... but those have additional sexist connotations.

@Sven Yargs, are there idioms for "the religion of the Pope or the defecatory practices of a wild bear"?

@abcd: There are idiomatic rhetorical questions that people (in the U.S., anyway) may ask in response to an obvious question, among the most common of which are "Is the Pope Catholic?" and "Does a bear shit in the woods?" These could easily be transformed into statements of the form "Next you're going to tell me that the Pope is Catholic," etc.

No shit, Sherlock
(vulgar, colloquial, sarcastic, somewhat derogatory)

A riposte to someone who has just said something obvious

A reference to the fictional detective Sherlock Holmes, pretending that the interlocutor has just made a great deduction.
[Wiktionary]

Given at the duplicate. Please check for likely duplicates, to avoid bloat.

@EdwinAshworth I think the server can carry the load of the duplicates ;-). And for the users it actually increases usefulness.

In school we used the less-vulgar "no dip, Sherlock" (though I was never sure exactly why). "No shit" can stand alone and has a clear trajectory from "shit" meaning bullshit/malarkey.

Interestingly there exist something similar in German ("Ohne Scheiß") meaning "It's quite true" (the speaker pointing out that he/she's not kidding).

It depends on inflection. "No shit" can mean both, "Everyone knows this" or "Oh wow, you're not kidding"

@Peter 'I think the server can carry the load of the duplicates. And for the users it actually increases usefulness.' is a criticism of the whole anti-bloat aim of SE sites. Imagine a textbook that covered the same topics again and again.

@EdwinAshworth Well, this is not a duplicate, since the other question asks about "clean" phrases. All answers here are valid answers to this specific question; they may be rude!

... And ELU becomes just another Q and A site, having lost credibility.

I often hear “thanks, Sherlock” as a cleaner version.

While I don't have North American experience, I have heard "Tell me something I don't know" used in such situations. It indicates that the previous remark has not done this.
For example, from Chatterbox, ed. by J.E. Clarke - p99 on Google Books:

'Why hers is black!'
'I am perfectly aware of that; also that yours is purple, Bea's brown, mine and Kittie's gray. Tell me something I don't know,' said Kat flippantly. 'I wish ours were black, it's so stylish.'

and from Freedomways - p263 on Google Books

"He's a mighty mean cracker,"Sarah told him.
"Tell me something I don't know," Moose Coleman stated grimly.


This phrase fits the question well, but it would benefit from some published examples or references, such as this

Are you looking for something colloquial? How about:

duh interjection
2 —used derisively to indicate that something just stated is all too obvious or self-evident        Well,
duh! Source:
Merriam-Webster—duh

The Editors Blog calls duh:

an exclamation of exasperation or disdain over the explanation of
something obvious Source: The Editor's Blog—Spelling
Interjections and
Exclamations

(You needn’t tell me that is grammatical but quite formal.)

Given at the duplicate. Please check for likely duplicates, to avoid bloat.

Interestingly, the false antonym "no duh" means the exact same thing as "duh".

If you want to be critical, I'm sure there are many put-downs, among which "Thank you, Captain Obvious!" Another could be "Gee, thanks!" if said with a sarcastic tone.
Captain Obvious

(A sarcastic or disparaging name for) someone who makes an obvious or
superfluous statement.
2022 Thanks captain obvious! Like we couldn't figure that out ourselves.
@BugAcer 21 March in twitter.com (accessed 22 Mar. 2022)
[OED online]


(humorous, usually derogatory or sarcastic) Someone who makes
superfluous or obvious statements.
Thank you, Captain Obvious!
Wiktionary

If you are want something close to non-critical, perhaps
"That goes without saying"

goes without saying: (with non-personal subject) to be obvious or generally understood; to need no mention or explanation.
[OED online]

“You needn’t tell me that” is correct, but on the stern side.  "I'm (well) aware of that (thank you)" is perhaps more common and tactful. (The two literal translations in your question are ungrammatical as written.)

How are the two literal translations in my question ungrammatical? Can you elaborate? How would you fix those? Thank you.

What do you mean by "on the stern side"? Do you mean grammatically it's too formal or the attitude's not nice? If it's kinda rude, then it does the job.

@abcd We don't use the impersonal "it" here ("It doesn't need you...") but rather "You don't have to ..." or "You needn't..." // AmE uses needn't less frequently than BrE. // "You needn't tell me that" sounds formal and somewhat scolding in AmE.

Thumbs up for 'That goes without saying.'

'Thank you, Captain Obvious' given at the duplicate. Please check for likely duplicates, to avoid bloat.

@EdwinAshworth It's not clear (or no longer clear) what "the duplicate" refers to.

Answers merely repeats of those at Is there a phrase to indicate the other party said something obvious? (itself closed as a duplicate).

“You don’t say” seems to fit the desired meaning and sentiment. When used ironically/sarcastically with flat or tetchy affect, perhaps raising your eyebrows or even rolling your eyes, it expresses irritation without being vulgar (though it is not polite). It also carries an implication that the other person stated something obvious (as opposed to something known to you specifically).
Note that it can also be used without irony to express genuine surprise.

"Ya/you think?" can be used to sarcastically question someone's statement about something that is very obvious to everyone present. It implies not that just you knew something already, but that it would be obvious to anyone.
As an example, suppose you're in a restaurant after closing time and the waitstaff starts to put chairs on the tables, turn the lights off, and vaccuum the floor. Your companion, who has been lingering over their meal, says "Oh, they want us to leave," - a reasonable response might be, "Ya think?".

No clue why this is downvoted, it's corroborated on this very site and elsewhere: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93487/what-is-the-origin-of-the-expression-ya-think  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_think

Teaching grandmother to suck eggs
It means to explain a task to someone who already knows how to do it, possibly better than the teacher. It's a trifle archaic but still current enough to be understood.

In my experience, this one is usually used the other way around as a sort of pre-emptive apology for what you're about to say. "I don't mean to teach you how to suck eggs, but "

Again in German there exist equivalents like "Teaching a fish to swim" or "teaching a bird to fly" (both considered to be unnecessary)

"I am aware (of that)..."  It's polite unless said with a harsher tone.

Similarly: "I've heard of that..."

If it's something that you know/believe but which might be controversial if said in the wider public, you might respond with

[You're] Preaching to the choir

